# How to connect Couchbase for my Symfony project?

Tags: php, symfony, couchbase

I couldn't find any good resource/article yet now to connect Couchbase server in my Controller page. I have installed PHP SDK successfully. But my code is not working. Object is not properly called. See my test code here. Object for ex. CouchbaseCluster, openBucket is not getting called properly.

```
public function getConnection() {

    // Connect to Couchbase Server
    $cluster = new CouchbaseCluster('http://127.0.0.1:8091');
    $bucket = $cluster->openBucket('beer-sample');

    // Retrieve a document
    $result = $bucket->get('aass_brewery-juleol');
    $doc = $result->value;
    echo $doc->name . ', ABV: ' . $doc->abv . "\n";
}
```

Please help me out what the namespace or use will be included there.

Thanks in advance for giving some good point or references on Symfony and Couchbase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official Couchbase PHP SDK, is not just a PHP library, they distribute their SDK through `libcouchbase` package and a PECL extension.

The installation process is [well documented](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/sdk/php/start-using-sdk.html) .

Once installed, make sure the extension is loaded by checking [phpinfo.](http://php.net/phpinfo.)

Assuming that installation went through succesfully, you should be able to use the Classes, methods exposed by the PECL extention.

The issue you are likely facing is that you are using a class from the [Global Space](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.global.php) in a Namespaced Class.

Observe the `\`

```
 $cluster = new \CouchbaseCluster('http://127.0.0.1:8091');
```

mostly will solve the issue you are facing .

Comment: Thanks for the "well documented" comments.  PHP is very flexible here, so we worked hard to make it approachable and still comprehensive.  Feedback is welcome if there's something we can improve!

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Could you suggest me now why php_couchbase.dll file is not working as an extension? It shows me now:
**Unable to load dynamic library 'E:\xampp\php\ext\php_couchbase.dll' The specified module could not found.**

Comment: By the way. It has solved. In your given documentation link they said to insert extension=couchbase.dll in php.ini file. But I couldn't get couchbase.dll in anywhere. How can I solve that? Please help me out.

Comment: you have to download the appropriate archive from this page http://developer.couchbase.com/server/other-products/release-notes-archives/php-sdk .. when you extract it. you get a dll..  Going through the documentation actually helps to solve issues .

Comment: Everything goes fine now for my creating a php file to connect database and CRUD operation. But still I have a problem. In my Symphony controller page it shows error when run: "Attempted to load class "CouchbaseCluster" from the global namespace. Did you forget a "use" statement?" Have you any solution for that in my Symfony project?

Comment: are you instantiating with `\CouchbaseCluster` or just `\CouchbaseCluster` ?

Comment: It's a brilliant solution. Many many thanks. Could you say me please why we need to give \ sign for just curiosity to know it.